# How to get value of : First user who accepted the ownership of Lead from particular queue

Tags: reporting, field-history

In my sandbox when a new lead is created its assigned to a TCC queue. Then someone from TCC team queue will accept the ownership of queue.

Now i want to see report of : who accepted how many Leads from TCC queue.

I have enabled history tracking for ownership field but since we can not filter report using the OLD or NEW value of owner, i am thinking of creating a text field to store the value of first user who accepted the ownership from TCC queue.

Is my approach correct? Any suggestions on how can i achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems correct for me. To achieve this functionality you can create a text field called **Record Assigned Owner**.

Then create a workflow rule and update the field when owner is changed. You can write following formula in workflow.

```
if(AND(OwnerId = "Queue_ID", ISBLANK(Record_Assigned_Owner__C)), OwnerId,null)
```

The formula is checking specific queue id and Record Assigned Owner as blank then it will update the Ownerid.
You could achieve it through trigger also, but workflow approach is always preferable.

Comment: Hi Prabhat, Thanks for reply but i think workflow won't run after the user accepts the ownership of lead from queue. And if it is so then how that field will be updated with owner?

Comment: Also i tried workflow solution its not working

Comment: Where you are facing the problem exactly. Does the owner field is not getting update ?

Comment: Custom owner field is still blank   : https://unsee.cc/gedupito/

Comment: Never Mind....I found the error. (i was updating wrong field ;) )